# Will the size of bitfield be saved even if assigment is via pointer?

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

Let's assume I have

```c
struct foo
{
unsigned int bar : 7;
unsigned int next_field : 1;
}
void funct()
{
struct foo demo;
demo.next_field = 0;
unsigned char *barptr  = (unsigned char *)&demo;
/*1 = 00000001, bar can contain only 7 bits*/
*barptr = 1;
}
```

since `bar` is 7 bit where as `char` is 8 bits, what will happen? Will  bar be filled with zeros and next_field contain the 1?
Will the result be:

```
0000000  1
|_____| |_|
  bar
```

or

```
0000001  0
|_____| |_|
  bar
```

or:

```
0000000  0
|_____| |_|
  bar
```

I would check using my compiler but I don't know wether this behavior is implementation-defined, in witch case the compiler can be misleading.

Comment: Please report on your experiments results. Especially the one where you write 128 to `* barptr`. Also please make a [mre] of that experiment.

Comment: Please also report all the warnings you get - using strict warnigns. At the very least the equivalent of `-Wall`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala One of the upvotes is by me. Because while the OP has a severe misunderstanding, it is one which, clarified, can be an useful insight to new C programmers. (In spite of having also proposed how to improve the question.)

Comment: The code in the question still does not compile, nor does it produce the error OP claims it does, and the fixed code that does produce the error, **fails to compile in MSVC!** All in all a completely invalid question.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala you are correct. I have fixed the q now

Comment: but now it does not produce the bitfield error. It produces a warning because it has a constraint violation.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I know, this is why I have deleted the error

Comment: Ok, now it is better, and answerable!

Comment: @KamilCuk it had the constraint violation warning, but it is not important for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point you are quite brutally crossing borders of clean programming.

```
unsigned char *barptr  = &foo.bar; /* first version of the question */
unsigned char *barptr  = (unsigned char *)&demo; /* after edit  */
```

You are using the address of something which is not a `char` in at least two ways and write it to a pointer to `char`.

After that using that pointer basically tells the compiler "Here is a char. Honest. Believe me. Trust me. Just write it." Whether or not you do that with a type cast (one of the differences between the two versions) is actually irrelevant.

```
*barptr = 1;
```

Any "knowing bitsize of bitfield" which the compiler had before have been flattened by you blatantly lying to the compiler afterwards.

If you want to cleanly write `bar` via a pointer do it like this

```
struct foo *demop;
demop = &demo;
demop->bar = 1;
```

Comment: now that the code was updated this answer is somewhat invalid :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, it is a moving target question now. And you answered the newer version. I am surprised by that. The usual way of handling moving target questions, among the more experienced StackOverflow users (as far as I understand it), is to undo the change which relevantly changed the question. Without your answer I would roll back now. Could you change your answer to match the old version and agree with rolling back?

Comment: there was no point in the old question, the code did not work as the question claimed, as I noted in the comment back then. It asked "why does this give an error in GCC while it works in MSVC" when the truth was that it didn't work in MSVC.

Comment: Oh well. Now I tried to change my answer so that it answers old and new version of the question. Both of you, avivgood2 and @AnttiHaapala, please comment on whether it satisfies you. avivgood2 because I want my answer to still be helpful for you. Antti because I value your input.

Answer (score 2):

> 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators
>
> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function
> designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that
> designates an **object that is not a bit-field** and is not declared with
> the `register` storage-class specifier.

You cannot take address of a bit-field. This action is illegal in C.

Comment: @Pynchia https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf

Comment: Thank you,  but a clean direct link would be much better. And in the body of the answer

Answer (score 1):

In C it is allowed to modify bytes of an object using a pointer to `unsigned char`. However, as the layout of a bitfield is implementation-defined, it is implementation-defined what value this will result in. Furthermore, the member `bar` is not initialized before the bytes are modified, so *anything* is indeed possible, including a compiler assuming that it should contain garbage, even though the byte that contains the `bar` member in entirety would be initialized by it.

And if the layout is big-endian, it might even be, although unlikely, that the latter bits of the bitfield would reside at the *end* of the bytes, so that the values of both `next_field` and `bar` would be completely unaffected by the change.

Now, would you initialize it with a default initializer,

```
struct foo demo = {0};
```

after

```
unsigned char *barptr  = (unsigned char *)&demo;
*barptr = 1;
```

we could say that either `bar` or `next_field` could have one bit set, or they would be completely zeroed; and you would have to check the behaviour from the compiler manuals. In Linux for example, the [*ABI documents*](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) specify the bitfield layout for each architecture.